# E/launcher - stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, bdd, cucumberjs

I have these two scenarios defined:

```
@high @basic
  Scenario Outline: dropdown boxes exist
    When I am on the Enernoc application
    Then application is running
    And <dropdown box> is present

    Examples:
      |dropdown box|
      |templateSelection|
      |templateDeliveryPathSelection|
      |templateLocaleSelection|


  @high
  Scenario Outline: dropdown boxes appear and work as expected.
    Given I am on the Enernoc application
    Then application is running
    When click <box>
    Then <option> present in <box>

    Examples:
      |box| option|
      |templateSelection| Apparent Energy |
      |templateDeliveryPathSelection| EMAIL |
```

The code is:

```
Given(/^I am on the Enernoc application$/, function (callback) {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; // To be added if the application is non-angular
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize(); // To maximize the window
        browser.get("http://d3qdeak1vbuqh4.cloudfront.net/template_definition").then(function () {
            callback(); // To tell the cucumber that we are done with this step
        });
    });
Then(/^application is running$/, function (callback) {
        browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(3000);
        callback();
    });
Then(/^(.*) is present$/, function (dropdown,callback) {
        expect(element(by.id(dropdown)).isPresent());
        callback();
    });
When(/^click (.*)$/, function (dropdown,callback) {
        EnernocHomePage.clickDropdown(dropdown,callback);
    });
Then(/^(.*) present in (.*)$/, function (value,dropdown,callback) {
        EnernocHomePage.checkDropdown(value,dropdown);
        callback();
    });
```

In another file I have this code:

```
clickDropdown: function(dropdown,callback) {
        element(by.id(dropdown)).click().then(function () {
           callback();
        });
    },

    checkDropdown: function (value,dropdown) {
       expect(element(by.id(dropdown)).$('option:checked').getText()).eventually.equal(value);
    },
```

I am receiving an error in the output informing about this:

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
[12:15:17] E/launcher - StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

How can I fix it? It seems that for some reason, it is not finding the element when trying to access it. Any idea?

The error seems to be in the checkDropdown section as per the detailed output.

Comment: Any idea which function is throwing the stale element reference error? click or check?

Comment: Can you share the code of the `element` function? I guess that it's a wrapper that you wrote around `driver.findElement`, but I have a feeling that there's more to it than that, and maybe there lies the root cause...

Comment: A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the first being more common than the second:

The element has been deleted entirely or the element is no longer attached to the DOM. Please go step by step and find on which element this error occurs, after that one strategy is to define it again and then interact with it.